# Why my interval is still counting and didn't stop at 0?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I wonder why my countdown didn't stop at 0, the "Time's Up" log are still logging infinitely.

Here's my code:

```
let timer = 6;
setInterval(function () {
  if (timer > 0) {
    timer--;
  console.log(timer);
  } else {
    console.log("Time's Up");
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: What is `timer`, exactly? Have you read the documentation on [`clearInterval`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/clearInterval) and what its argument means?

Comment: Oops! Sorry, I already edit it. I already read that and CMIIW, argument is something you passed on to a function. And there is parameter, which is inside function parenthese itself.

Comment: No, I’m asking what `clearInterval`’s argument means, not what the term “argument”, in general, means. `clearInterval`’s argument is the timer ID which is the return value of `setInterval`. You don’t use the return value of `setInterval`. Instead you use some arbitrary integer variable. When you call `clearInterval`, you call `clearInterval(0)`. `0` is _not_ the timer ID of this `setInterval` function.

Comment: Ah! I see, somethings like "Hmm... I don't know what's to clear" Instead if I use let myCountDown = setInterval(), it'll says "Ok, I'll stop the interval on myCountDown" Well that make sense. Oh, thanks btw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clearInterval` needs to know the action you want to cancel. In this case, the action is actually your `setInterval`, so just assign it to a variable and use that variable as a parameter for `clearInterval`.

```
 const myInterval = setInterval(() => {
  if (timer > 0) {
    timer--;
  console.log(timer);
  } else {
    console.log("Time's Up");
    clearInterval(myInterval);
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Ah! I see, somethings like "Hmm... I don't know what's to clear" Instead if I use let myCountDown = setInterval(), it'll says "Ok, I'll stop the interval on myCountDown" Well that make sense. Oh, thanks btw!

Answer (score 0):

What I understand that you are using timer as a variable. So, you are doing one mistake, you are giving wrong parameter inside clearInterval method. You can stop clearInterval method by the code written below:-

**NOTE:- I just substitute console.log with document.write to show the Output on screen.**

```js
var timer = 5;
var myinterval = setInterval(function () {
    if (timer > 0) {
      timer--;
    document.write(timer+"<br>");
    } else {
      document.write("Time's Up");
      clearInterval(myinterval);
    }
  }, 1000);
```

Comment: Ah! I see, somethings like "Hmm... I don't know what's to clear" Instead if I use let myCountDown = setInterval(), it'll says "Ok, I'll stop the interval on myCountDown" Well that make sense. Oh, thanks btw!